# Что значит {% if not is_frame %} в html

Tags: html, django

Я начинающий программист и не могу самостоятельно найти ответ на вопрос:

что значит следующий отрывок кода в html-документе?

```
{% if not is_frame %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: на праздниках насмотрелся битву экстрасенсов и кажется у меня появилась сила экстрасенса, не зря я воду заряжал у телевизора и пил, судя по всему есть блок `{% if not is_frame %}` который заканчивается `{% endif %}`(или что-то подобное), так вот весь тот html код, который будет находится в внутри этого блока будет выведен, если html-документ выводится не во фрейме

Comment: Это же не чистый HTML. Файл какое расширение имеет ? Могу предположить что это Twig к примеру.

Comment: @tCode да, он заканчивается `{% endif %}` и то что между - выводится. Но что это за конструкция или язык программирования?

Comment: @EmptyMan это конструкция, предположу, какого-то шаблонизатора из какой-то CMS, написанной скорее всего на `PHP`, дальше в коде движка эта конструкция преобразуется в условие `if`

Comment: @Moonvvell это не чистый HTML. Расширение `.html`. Знаю, что используется Dgango, JavaScript и JQuery

Comment: @EmptyMan, это говорит о том, что файл подвергается препроцессингу, перед тем, как отдать его по запросу

Comment: Вообще это код с питона

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Связка `{% if not is_frame %}` заканчивается `{% endif %}`.

Вычитал, что это Django (в моем случае 1.6) с подключением модуля `django.shortcuts` и использованием `render_to_response`.

Выглядит это примерно так в файле с расширением `.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
    context['is_frame'] = False
```

Почему-то в моем случае используется `from django.shortcuts import redirect`, может он и использует `render_to_response`.

Как я понял, Django перехватывает выражение из скобок `{%  %}` и проверяет значение `is_frame` на условие `{% if not is_frame %}`.

Не понятным остается синтаксис `{%  %}` - откуда и что это?

Comment: `{%  %}` нужен чтобы в коде обработчик понимал что ему нужно

Comment: Это синтаксис шаблонизатора Django

Comment: Вообще, почитайте какой-нибудь учебник по основам django, например http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/